# Docker/nginx [windows10] - change page on linked folder and show changes directly in the browser

Tags: nginx, docker

**Question**: How can I change the index.html file in docker/nginx and see the changed results in my browser? 
The index.html is on a private folder linked to the standard nginx folder.

**What did I do**: 
After installing docker and nginx via the official pages, I created a folder under /Users/me123/docker/webapp/html. In this folder I created an index.html file.

I linked this folder to the default nginx folder via the following command. I used both the RO and not-RO versions:

```
docker run --name nginx -p 80:80 -v //c/Users/me123/docker/webapp/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx
```

So, when editing the file (with e.g. Notepad++) I expected to see the updates. Alas, even in firefox with ctrl-F5 or control-refresh-icon. So, this is really not a caching problem. I visited the page via 192.n.n.n/index.html.

When I delete the index.html file, then I got an error. When I put the index.html file back I see the old index.html content.

I saw a post that this may be due to inode-synchronisation/updates. So a 'docker restart nginx' would be sufficient. Alas. Even the sequence 'docker stop nginx' and 'docker rm nginx-package-via-number' won't help.

When I add a new file to my local /Users/me123/docker/webapp/html folder, I immediately see the contents.

So, how can I change the index.html file and see the changed results in my browser?

Comment: Are you using boot2docker for Windows?

Comment: No. 
Just plain install of docker and nginx.

Comment: Thought might be something related to https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/652 since you're not on boot2docker then probably not. Probably bring it to github and see if anyone else having the same problem. Should be pretty easy to replicate but be explicity tell them is a windows box

Comment: Do you have any caching mechanism in place? (eg memcache, squid, varnish, etc)? If yes, try flushing it.

Comment: To be sure - not in the browser. [1] I cleared the cache, no changes. [2] I did in firefox both ctrl-F5 and ctrl-resynch. Nothing changes. 
I did a fresh install. So, just VM-box, docker engine, and nginx via docker run etc. How can I verify this 1 step further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add  tags in my index.html to prohibit caching - alas.

The solution is by changing the nginx.conf file.

Use the following and the problem is solved:

```
sendfile        off;
```

By default it is set on.